# How does forEach() return values by taking document as a parameter for an Array of Documents?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, document

This is my declaration of an Array of Documents :

```
    let Arr = 
      [
           {abc: 123 , def: 456},
           {abc: 999 , def: 888},
           {abc: 777 , def: 333}
      ];
```

To get all the values of abc, I use :

```
Arr.forEach( function (element , index)  
{
    console.log(element.abc);
} );
```

Which is the standard definition of the forEach() function.

But the tutorial which I am following declared the array in a different way and used it to get values of abc as such :

```
let Doc = { abc: 123 , def: 456};
let Arr = [Doc];
Arr.push({abc: 999, def: 888});
Arr.push({abc: 777, def: 333});
```

And then used the forEach() function as such :

```
Arr.forEach(Doc => console.log(Doc.abc));
```

1. How does that work? i.e traversal using Document?
2. Do I have to declare it in a similar manner? i.e First a Document declaration, then making Array containing that document and then pushing the rest of the values into the mould ?

Comment: 1. `Doc !== document`, they just use a different name for that parameter. Your `element` is their `Doc`; 2. No. This looks more like a _"This are different ways how you can get an element (like an object) into an array"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first method, array of objects is declared once. Whereas in the second, separate objects are created and then it is pushed into the array.

```
let Doc = { abc: 123 , def: 456}; // Separate object is created and stored in variable `Doc`.

let Arr = [Doc]; // The Object created is inserted in array, similar to `push`.

Arr.push({abc: 999, def: 888}); // Object is directly pushed into the array, without creation of separate variable and storing object in it.

Arr.push({abc: 777, def: 333});
```

In the first `forEach`, regular function is used as a callback, whereas in second `arrow based` function is used as a callback.

`Arr.forEach(Doc => console.log(Doc.abc));` -> In this `Doc` refer to the object. The `Doc` does not refer to variable `let Doc = { abc: 123 , def: 456};`. Instead of `Doc`, you can give different name as well.

```js
let Doc = { abc: 123 , def: 456};
let Arr = [Doc];
Arr.push({abc: 999, def: 888});
Arr.push({abc: 777, def: 333});

Arr.forEach(Doc => {
  console.log(Doc);
});
```

Comment: Is this the only way to declare and define it to use the arrow based callback function?

Comment: No. You can use arrow based function in your array as well. It doesn't have anything to do with declaration of array.